# Trouble with converting polygons (shapefiles) to raster on QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, shapefile, vector, rasterization

I have a **shapefile** layer
[image: iceberg polygon layer]

And I wish to convert this to a raster:

This layer was geocoded over **RADARSAT SAR** images, example picture below:
[image]

I go to Rasterize (Vector to Raster) using GDAL:

I input the following:

[image]

Since I have a SAR image with a pixel size of 20m, I select the SAR image for the output extent. The problem is I end up with this output, and absolutely nothing shows up on the project.

[image]

I am stumped. I have tried numerous methods. In the attribute table there is only one column called 'ID' because all I need is the number of icebergs here. I will carry out the other tasks on python. That being said, the attribute table does not include coordinates (x and y) for the polygons.

Is this the problem?

First I tried to see if the CRS was wrong. I then tried to warp the SAR image into a new CRS, and then ran the GDAL conversion again, but the same result.

I am trying to show a raster of the iceberg shapefile over the SAR image.

Comment: If the input layer is in EPSG:4326 and pixel size is 20 units it makes 20 degrees that is about 2200 kilometers.

Comment: I believe I've solved the issue. I needed to reproject the shapefile into the CRS used in the project for it to work which was EPSG 32633 UTM Zone 33. Now I have a raster of my shapefile, hopefully that means the coordinates are saved and I can process each pixel on python.